# I have Infinitely messed up a new MCU tag!

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retagging

So in light of a [new question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174154/did-loki-steal-the-tesseract-again) about *Thor: Ragnarok*, which was really asking for information that will come out (and was answered by) material in *Avengers: Infinity War*, I decided to create a tag for that film. I figured this would allow those who are sensitive to spoilers to be able to ignore the tag. Anyway...

I went ahead and created [avengers-infinity-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-infinity-wars).

*However*, most fans of the MCU will quickly notice my mistake. The actual name of the film is *Avengers: Infinity War*, not plural...

I went to try to create the correct tag and allow the misspelled tag to self delete but I was presented with this message:

[image: tag creation flag]

> You are attempting to create the tag [avengers-infinity-war]; however the tag [avengers-infinity-wars] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.

So here I am on meta... what is the course of actions or events to correct this?

<sub>Title note: Obviously the fix was pretty easy, we just have a habit of making silly titles for our tag questions.</sub>

Comment: -1 for the silly title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the tag has only been used on one question so far, an easy solution would have been:

- remove the incorrect tag;
- wait a day for it to be automatically wiped from the system along with other zero-use tags;
- create the correct tag instead.

But since you've raised this on meta and I'm here, I went ahead and used mod powers to rename [avengers-infinity-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-infinity-wars) to [avengers-infinity-war](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avengers-infinity-war).

Comment: Thanks for being here so quickly! Even better that it is related to a Thor question and you got to "hammer" it.... the small things bring me chuckles....

Comment: @Skooba (Randal) Thor?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the correct course of action if the tag in question is the *only* tag on its only question (so that it can't be removed)?

Comment: @Kevin Then I guess you could flag that question for a mod to rename the tag.